# How to apply black and white effect to a color video in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

In my application I have a color video which I want to make as black and white video. Is there any framework that supports this in iOS? If so, how to implement that effect on color video?

Can anyone help in this regard?

Answer (score 2):

A bit late here, but you should check out [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/).

It can be compiled as a static lib for the iPhone and can convert video (frame by frame) to grayscale or two color.

You can start [here](http://lambdajive.wordpress.com/2010/11/24/cross-compiling-opencv-for-iphone/). There are other resources for doing this floating around.

Answer (score 0):

HI Lakshmi this might be familiar  to you that at least 24 frames make a clip of video so you have to use a tool like movie maker so that you can see the video frame by frame and edit each frame.

Answer (score 0):

See the opensource Framework named: GPUImage https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/ 
The filter name GPUImageGrayscaleFilter is what you want 
This framework included the sample code, so you can learn how to use GPUImageGrayscaleFilter in your apps easily