# How to play video in black/white

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to apply black and white effect to a color video in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5739962/how-to-apply-black-and-white-effect-to-a-color-video-in-ios)

Hi,

Can anyone help me how we play video in black/white mode.

Thanks.

Comment: HEy gandesh.... is it you? :D if not then sorry.. I'm giving you worse idea, just put a black overlay on ur movie player with transparency of 50%.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunatly, doesnt seem that the MPMoviePlayerController gives you the ability to adjust such a feature, so i would say it is not possible right now with the build in movie player.